# Is passing a void * to the function not good practice?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, is passing a `void *` as an argument to a `free` function bad practice? If not, how will the function know how much memory to free starting from the location that `void *` points to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`free()` only needs the start address of the memory block; its contents don't matter. That's why it actually has a `void*` in its signature (so it doesn't matter what kind of pointer you pass, it will always get a `void*`).

> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

As you can see you may only free memory allocated by one of these functions - and they store the size of the block internally.

---

In case you are curious, the information doesn't even need to be stored in a separate structure at a single location; for example it's common for various replacements of the default `malloc`/`free` to allocate N+M bytes of memory with M being the size of the metadata struct. At the address returned by that allocation they store their own metadata (such as the allocated size) and then return ptr+M which points to the memory right after the metadata.

When freeing that memory it can simply subtract M from the address to get the initial pointer, which points to the metadata.

Comment: Ok, if the size of the block returned by malloc, calloc or realloc is stored internally, then free() knows how much memory to give back to the heap. But what do you mean stored internally? Just out of curiosity, where is the size of the allocated block stored?

Comment: See the second part of my answer. That's one possible way to do it.

Comment: Also, read about explicit memory allocators to see how free knows how much memory to deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

free doesn't need the data type, `void *` will work fine.  How much memory is released is managed internally.  What is important is that you pass to `free` a value previously obtained from a compatible allocate function: `malloc` and it's friends.

Answer (score 0):

`free()` implementation is supposed to know from the passed pointer how big heap cell to release is. Pointer must be obtained from `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. The exact way may differ from platform to platform - no technical details should be assumed for the sake of portable code.

`void*` is a good way to specify argument type, because then it can enjoy implicit downgrade conversion from any other pointer type.

Answer (score -1):

There is no really freeing memory ,it's just allow to other programs allocate memory too here.
BTW ,if you want the length of the right memory you have the function `strlen`. (Not sure about that one)